# Canonical factorization of a certain function

Tags: functions, relations, equivalence-relations, function-and-relation-composition

> Given the sets $A=${$x_i|1\leq i\leq 9$} and $B=${$y_j|1\leq j\leq 6$} we consider the map $f:A\to B$ defined by:
>   $$f(x_1)=y_1 \qquad f(x_2)=y_1 \qquad f(x_3)=y_3 \\
> f(x_4)=y_3 \qquad f(x_5)=y_3 \qquad f(x_6)=y_4 \\
> f(x_7)=y_4 \qquad f(x_8)=y_4 \qquad f(x_9)=y_6$$
>   In the set $A$ we define the following binary relation:
>   $$x_iRx_j \iff f(x_i)=f(x_j)$$
>   Show that $R$ is an equivalence relation and find the canonical factorization of $f$.

In order to show that $R$ is an equivalence relation I have to comprove that it is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive, so:

$R$ is reflexive: $\forall i\in A \quad iRi\quad f(x_i)=f(x_i)$

$R$ is symmetric: $\forall i,j\in A \quad iRj \quad$then, if $f(x_i)=f(x_j)$, $f(x_j)=f(x_i)$, so $jRi$

$R$ is transitive: $\forall i,j,k\in A\quad iRj\quad jRk\quad$ then we have $f(x_i)=f(x_j)$ and $f(x_j)=f(x_k)$, from which follows $f(x_i)=f(x_k)$, so $iRk$.

Now I have to find the canonical factorization of $f$, but I have no clear idea about how to do it. Could you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You need to formulate two functions $A\to A/R\to B$ such that their composition is $f$.

Comment: **Attempt:** As $A\to A/R$, I have formulated:

$g:[x_i]=${$x_j|x_iRx_j$}.

The other function $h:A/R\to B$, that returns the image of $[x_i]$, should be:

$h([x_1])=y_1 \quad h([x_3])=y_3 \quad h([x_6])=y_4 \quad h([x_9])=y_6$.

So then $f$ would be $h\circ g$.

Is it right?

Comment: Yes, correct. Do you see the bijection $A/R \to \mathrm{ran}(f) $?

Comment: You mean this?
As the independent elements of $ran(f)$ are $y_1$, $y_3$, $y_4$, $y_6$ and:
$$[x_1]\to y_1$$
$$[x_3]\to y_3$$
$$[x_6]\to y_4$$
$$[x_9]\to y_6$$
Then $A/R\to ran(f)$ is bijective.

Comment: Yes. You seem to get it clearly. One more addendum: this picture is very general and holds for *every* function $f$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information!!

Comment: It looks like there is a minor discrepancy in the definition of a function factorization. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4332693/the-canonical-map-from-operatornamecoimf-to-operatornamecdmf?noredirect=1#comment9035566_4332693